# Command bar button error visualization whit IsDynamicOverflowEnabled

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a simple bar commander with buttons. when I try to resize the window, with IsDynamicOverflowEnabled enabled, when there is no space in the command bar, the primary buttons move to the secondary ones.
This creates this graphic problem:

[image]

The Select button is cut.

this is the XAML of commandBar:

```
<CommandBar x:Name="command" DefaultLabelPosition="Right" IsDynamicOverflowEnabled="True">
```

this is for for any appBarButton:

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="searchAppBarButton" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonRevealStyle}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Search" Click="searchAppBarButton_Click" Label="Search">
     <AppBarButton.Content>
            <FontIcon x:Name="IconSearch" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE094;" />
     </AppBarButton.Content>
</AppBarButton>
```

UPDATE: 
I found the problem, the problem is the style AppBarButtonRevealStyle of the appbarbutton.
removing the style works correctly.
this is the complete code:

```
        <CommandBar Background="Transparent" DefaultLabelPosition="Right" IsDynamicOverflowEnabled="True">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"
                    FontSize="40"
                    Text="Command Bar"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton  ToolTipService.ToolTip="Layout" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonRevealStyle}" Label="Layout">
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE81E;" />
                </AppBarButton.Content>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton  ToolTipService.ToolTip="Layout" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonRevealStyle}" Label="Layout">
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE81E;" />
                </AppBarButton.Content>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton  ToolTipService.ToolTip="Layout" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonRevealStyle}" Label="Layout">
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE81E;" />
                </AppBarButton.Content>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton  ToolTipService.ToolTip="Layout" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonRevealStyle}" Label="Layout">
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE81E;" />
                </AppBarButton.Content>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="clearAllRecentDocument" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Clear All" 
                          Label="Clear All"
                          Icon="Delete" LabelPosition="Collapsed" ></AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew! After a lot of trial and looking into deeper sections of the style with the visual states, it turns out the issue that was causing that kinda problem was quite simple to resolve.

### Background:

So the `IsDynamicOverflowEnabled` property of the control is bounded with the 3 Visual States namely:

1. Overflow
2. OverflowWithToggleButtons
3. OverflowWithMenuIcons

Now, in your case the `OverflowWithMenuIcons` visual state is triggered (This is more of an FYI, just in case you want to apply some kind of special behaviors on the trigger).

### The Issue:

The issue is that in the Style `AppBarButtonRevealStyle`, on the top, there are two `Setters`:

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
<Setter Property="Width" Value="68" />
```

Because of which, even though the content gets adapted to the new layout, the `AppBarButton` still has a `HardCoded` `Width` of `68`. Also, since the `HorizontalAlignment` is set to left, even if the control took more width it would still not cover the whole clickable area.

### The Solution:

Well it's simple, Setting the `Width` to `Auto` would allow the content to automatically change it's width and setting the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` would allow the control to expand itself to stretch till the parent's `width` that'll cover the click area. The modified code is as below:

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
<Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
```

### How to get the style?

It's simple too, click on the `AppBarButtonRevealStyle` in your code and press F12, it'll open the `Generic.xaml`, copy the style from there (since you can't modify it there) and paste it in the `<Page.Resources>` Tag of your `xaml` and then replace the above code.

---

Just for reference I've put the modified style below:

### Modified Style:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="AppBarButton" x:Key="AppBarButtonRevealStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root"
                    MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                    MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="LabelOnRightStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="NaN" />
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullSize" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Compact">

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentViewbox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,14,0,14" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LabelOnRight">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentViewbox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="12,14,0,14" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextAlignment">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Left" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="8,15,12,17" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LabelCollapsed">

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Margin" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithMenuIcons">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Width" Value="16" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Height" Value="16" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Margin" Value="12,0,12,0" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Margin" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>

                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtonsAndMenuIcons">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Width" Value="16" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Height" Value="16" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Margin" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Margin" Value="76,0,12,0" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowNormal">

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowPointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowPressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Viewbox x:Name="ContentViewbox"
                            Height="20"
                            Margin="0,14,0,4"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" >
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                Height="20"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                            </Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            FontSize="12"
                            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                            TextAlignment="Center"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Margin="2,0,2,6"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="OverflowTextLabel"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            FontSize="15"
                            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                            TextAlignment="Left"
                            TextTrimming="Clip"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="12,0,12,0"
                            Padding="0,5,0,7"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                            <Border
                            x:Name="Border"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

I hope this solves the query, please do let me know if there is anything in the comments section

Comment: glad could help